# Need help converting a picture in byte in java

Tags: java, arrays, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to convert image to byte array in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211156/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array-in-java)

Hi,

Can anybody help me convert a picture to byte array in java?

thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow.com! Please provide some more context to your question: What format is the picture in that you want to convert (is it read from a file, does it come from some API call,...)? And how should it be converted to a byte array? What format do you want to use for the byte array? And why are you even doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point a File object to your picture location and then use a Scanner to read every byte. Something like:

int count=0;
File f = File("path");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

while(sc.hasNextByte())
{
  your_array[count] = sc.nextByte();
  count++;
}

I didnt test this so dont trust me on everything