# Is there a function to sum the rasters of two buffered images?

Tags: java, matrix, sum, bufferedimage, raster

I'm doing 2D filteing and want to do element by element addition on grayscale BufferedImages. Is there an existing function that will complete this for me or do i need to make one from scrach?

Is there some sort of matrix class that converts a raster to a matrix to simplyfy this problem?

Edit: here is the general gist of it

```
    BufferedImageOp opX = new ConvolveOp(new Kernel(3,3, kernelX));
    BufferedImageOp opY = new ConvolveOp(new Kernel(3,3, kernelY));
    BufferedImage filtImageX = opX.filter(sourceImage, null);
    BufferedImage filtImageY = opY.filter(sourceImage, null);
    BufferedImage outputImage = addBufferedImages(filtImageX, filtImageY);
```

**Grayscale Conversion:**

```
public void toGrayscale() { 
     BufferedImageOp op = new ColorConvertOp(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null); 
     sourceImage = op.filter(sourceImage, null); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with any java libs that do that for you.

You can get pixel at [i,j] with: `image.getRGB(i, j);`

```
BufferedImage image = ...;
BufferedImage resultImage = ...

int rgb= image.getRGB(i, j);
resultImage.setRGB(i, j, rgb);
```

You can also convert a buffered image to a byte array [ https://stackoverflow.com/a/7388025/1007845 ].
See this thread:  [how to convert image to byte array in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211156/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array-in-java)  to get a `WritableRaster`

**EDIT:**

It seems that WritableRaster might be useful in this case: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html

```
WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();

for(int h=0;h<height;h++) {
    for(int w=0;w<width;w++) {
        int colour = 127;
      raster.setSample(w,h,0,colour); 
   }
}
```

Comment: it says an interger is returned. How can you grab the apropriate pixel from that? (I know that an int is 4bytes each one represents a different channel)

Remember i've converted the colorspace to grayscale...so how do i interpret the information then.

Comment: @Adam for greyscale you calculate luminescence sth like: L = .30*R + .59*G + .11*B. Point I'm trying to make is that you still have integers. Could you post your code, it would help :)

Comment: @Adam don't you still have R,G,B values after your convolution? where is the code where you can't get colour of the pixel as int?

Comment: @Adam I edited the post to include WritableRaster. Try it out!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a direct way to do this.

But i can suggest a slightly underhanded approach. First, take your two images, and combine them into a single image with two bands. I'm hazy on the details of how to do this. I suspect you will want to create a [Raster](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/Raster.html) with a [BandedSampleModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BandedSampleModel.html), and then blit the contents of the other two images into its [DataBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/DataBuffer.html). Although it looks like you should be able to create a two-bank DataBuffer which uses the arrays of the source images' (one-banked) DataBuffers as banks, which would avoid copying.

Once you have a two-band image, simply apply a [BandCombineOp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BandCombineOp.html) which sums the bands. You will need to express the summation as a matrix, but that shouldn't be hard. I think it would be [1.0, 1.0],or [0.5, 0.5] if you want to rescale the result.