# loading a .bmp image into a 2-D byte array

Tags: java, bitmap, byte

I have a **30 x 40 pixel .bmp** file that I want to load into `inputData` that is declared like the following:

```
byte[][] inputData = new byte[30][40];
```

I relatively new to programming, so any one can tell me what classes should I being using to do so? thanks!

I don't know how to access the **.bmp** file in the same package and assign the corresponding `(x, y)` position onto my `2-D byte array`. So far I have the following:

```
for (int x = 0; x < inputData.length; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < inputData[x].length; y++)
    {
        // inputData[x][y] =
    }
}
```

Comment: [`ImageIO#read(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.File))

Comment: note that only grayscale or indexed-pallette images fit into a byte per pixel.

Comment: also note that BMP is a terrible format. Even at 30x40, a PNG is smaller than a BMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`ImageIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) in Java 5+ to read a BMP file into a [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html). The `BufferedImage` can already convert to `int[]`

In your case, extracting the **green** channel into the byte array:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("example.bmp"));
// you should stop here
byte[][] green = new byte[30][40];
for(int x=0; x<30; x++){
  for(int y=0; y<40; y++){
     int color = img.getRGB(x,y);
     //alpha[x][y] = (byte)(color>>24);
     //red[x][y] = (byte)(color>>16);
     green[x][y] = (byte)(color>>8);
     //blue[x][y] = (byte)(color);
  }
}
byte[][] inputData = green;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have Idea that 1 pixel is 1 byte, it is not true. RGB pixel is already 3 bytes per pixel. Also BMP file is not pixel array but rather compressed image. Simple load to array will not help you. Much better you use some ready libraries.

Look here:

GIF
[http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part1/Java/Chapter06/images.html](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jogl/loading-compressed-and-uncompressed-tgas-nehe-tutorial-jogl.html)

BMP
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html

TGA
http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jogl/loading-compressed-and-uncompressed-tgas-nehe-tutorial-jogl.html

Comment: For BMP example, this is for PDF only and it's not going to help in this case.

Comment: Main idea load BMP and then manipulate with byte array: also check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211156/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array-in-java

Loading BMP here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html