# Convert Image into binary array and binary array into image in java

Tags: java, android

AoA. Dear, i need function which can convert an image into binary to store in database and reverse conversion for this binary to image using java.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211156/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array-in-java

Comment: Not an Android guru or sure of your real needs but, is it not possible to store the file location in your database and just store the  image in the filesystem (or, just store the image in a well-known location in your filesystem [or on the classpath])?

Answer (score 0):

Use Base64 Class to convert it into String and then store in Database. You can convert it back into image whenever it is required.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html

Comment: bad idea ... common solution is to store only path in db and files in (surprise!) file system

Comment: why convert to base64 ? what good is that ? what's wrong with storing bytes ?