# Convert JPEG byte array to RGB

Tags: java, image, arrays, jpeg

I have an array of bytes which represents JPEG image. Is there any way to convert it directly to RGB array?
What i'm doing now is first create `Buffered Image` and thet get RGB array from it. Maybe, there is less expensive way to do this?

```
BufferedImage bufImage = new BufferedImage(640, 480, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(jpegBytes);
bufImage = ImageIO.read(stream);
int[] ib = bufImage.getRGB(0, 0, bufImage.getWidth(), bufImage.getHeight(), null, 0, bufImage.getWidth());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3211685/3082272

Comment: I don't want to create `BufferredImage` at all, I want to decompress from JPEG byte array to RGB

Comment: You can't directly convert a JPEG image byte data array to a RGB data array. Because JPEGs have some compression algorithm. And you'd have to implement your own logic to convert the compressed data array to the real RGB values. So the easiest way is, to use the addressed methods how you can convert it!

Comment: Thank you, i should leave it this way.

Comment: You don't need to create a `BufferedImage`... `ImageIO.read(..)` will create one for you, and the one you create is just garbage collected... Also, keep in mind that `BufferedImage` isn't some magic super-expensive object, it's a quite thin wrapper around the data array.