# Creating File With String Object

Tags: android, string, file, sockets

im writing a socket program which send and receive strings.
Im trying to build a file using this received strings that are sending from other side.
this is exactly done with text files but in others such an image file doesn't work and when complete, the image does not open!

in receiver:

```
file = new File(dir,FileName);
fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
dos = new DataOutputStream(fOut);
```

and when a msg received:

```
dos.write(msg.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

in sender:

```
File file = new File(FilePath);
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
```

...

```
isr.read(inputBuffer);
```

I have Tried this solution but the problem didn't fixed:

- Changing the UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1
- using output stream writer instead of data output stream.
- trying with smaller pictures than text file.

Comment: Make sure you flush to input and output streams. A common problem is that last bits of the data are left in the buffer.

Comment: yes i did it at first..

Answer (score 0):

ByteArrayOutputStream is useful converting bitmap to byte array.
after then, you using BitmapFactory, decodeByteArray is converting byte to bitmap.

Comment: thanks for attention. but the problem is that when i read a byte and convert it to string, it changes and was not the thing that I expect!

Comment: @user2962705 this page is help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211156/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array-in-java