# How to read a image in java and turn it to byte array?[use Lena.bmp 512x512 as example]

Tags: java, image, pixel

I want to analysis the pixel of lena.bmp (matlab)
but I don't know how to do it in java and store it to byte[]

I have read this aritle:

[how to convert image to byte array in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211156/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array-in-java)

But when I implement, I find some `pixel value that did't exist`.
For example , the pixel range is 0~255,
but I can not find '120' on pixel of this photo(lena.bmp).

There is my code

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Image_IO;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class ReadImage {
    public static void main (String []args){
        byte[] imageInByte;
        int [] kindOfPixel = new int [256];
        try{
            BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Project\\LSB_implement\\Lena.bmp"));
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write( originalImage, "bmp", baos );
            baos.flush();
            imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
            System.out.println(imageInByte.length);
            baos.close();

            for(int i=0;i<imageInByte.length;i++){
                kindOfPixel[imageInByte[i]+128]++;  //java byte defined -128~127  (+128)==> 0~256
            }

            for(int i=0;i<kindOfPixel.length;i++){  //show the pixel color value
                System.out.println(i+" , "+kindOfPixel[i]);
            }

        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }


   }    
}
```

I compare this information with the histogram of lena.bmp ,
but it seems have some different...

Comment: You'll get better results if you post the code you have so far.

Comment: What is the "pixel range"? the value/color of a pixel? May it be that the color assigned to '120' just never occurs on the image?

Comment: Not sure but i think Java uses signed data types only(while images are typically stored as unsigned data types) so when you get your `byte[]` it contains negative values, try shifting all of them by 128 and check the result. (posting your code will help with the solution)

Answer (score 1):

***First on java byte***

You are aware that the signed java byte ranges from -128 to 127.
You erred using 128 instead of calculating modulo 256:

That simply comes down to:

```
            kindOfPixel[imageInByte[i] & 0xFF]++;
```

To look for:

- an unsigned byte 120: < 127 hence **120**,
- an unsigned byte 130: >= 127 hence 130 - 256 = **-126**.

Modulo 256 calculation in the other direction goes:

```
byte signed = -126;
int unsigned = signed < 0 ? signed + 256 : signed;
int unsigned = signed & 0xFF; // or simply this
```

***The pixels***

A BMP file is not (only) a linearized list of pixels. So one better use the [int[] BufferedInage.getRGB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int[],%20int,%20int)):

```
int[] pixels = originalImage.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, null, 0, width);
```

***Remains the color representation***

BMP knows many variants: RGB, indexed etcetera. Indexed colors need a lookup in the palette.