# I'm trying to convert a image to byte array and byte array to a image

Tags: java, image, sockets, byte

I'm  making a client-server application and I would like to send images using a byte array. I'm using this code to convert the image into a byte array and then to a String:

```
// converting the image into bytes
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(filePath));
WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
DataBufferByte data = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
byte[] bytes = data.getData();
System.out.println("Size of array is " + bytes.length);
String base64String = Base64.encode(bytes);
System.out.println("size of base64String to send is " + base64String.length());
```

I'm getting this output:

> Size of array is 743904
>
> size of base64String to send is 991872
>
> size of the image that i want to send is 42.4KB

I'm using this code:

```
byte[] bytearray = Base64.decode(newMessage.getMessageToAdd());
System.out.println("Size of array is " + bytearray.length);
OutputStream outimg = null;
try {
    outimg = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(pathToSave));
    outimg.writewrite(bytearray);
} finally {
    if (outimg != null) {
        outimg.close();
    }
}
```

I get this output:

> size of array base64String recived is 991872 
> Size of array is 743904 
> and the size of the image created is 726KB

So from the output I understand that it recived and sent the image without getting a error but for some reason it fails at creating the image.

Comment: Could you clarify the output? I tried to format it but it's confusing, especially the second part. I just left it as is to avoid changing the meaning of your question.

Comment: Why are you not sending the contents of the file?

Comment: the output i get from the server is size of array base64String recived is 991872 Size of array is 743904

Comment: it craete a file of size 726KB

Comment: Indeed, why that unnecessary `ImageIO` fuzz? You don't need to manipulate (resize, crop, colorize, etc) the image, right? Just use `Files#readAllBytes()` or so.

Comment: @Maurice i'm sending an array of bytes

Comment: @AldhairZevallos why don't you simply read that array of bytes from the file?

Comment: @BalusC i tried changing it to Files.readAllBytes(new File(filePath).toPath()) and i dont know how but it works now, i  tried it before but it wasnt working, thank you

Comment: @maurice i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211156/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array-in-java and i tried with Files.readAllBytes before but idk why it wasnt working

Comment: @AldhairZevallos yes: readAllBytes would be a much better idea.