# Convertion of Base64 String to Bitmap returns null

Tags: android, bitmap, base64

I use following function to convert my base64 String to a bitmap:

```
public void displayUserImage() {
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);

    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
    imageViewUser.setImageBitmap(b);
}
```

When i excecute this function i get the following output:

```
D/skia: --- SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null
```

The base64 String is:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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…vE6kMvBBGKt6PrGoaTL52n3MkLg87TwfqO9csMVOnHlR9xmuRUswiqlP4j1DRfhloulhY5Lm4uzgZHQZrobrwhp81tGltGtr5f3dvOfqK5rwX46g1GZLfUTHb3TYCyZwr/X0r0SJVZQ4BIPcHjFYTnOp8TPja2BqYOfJNHPWHgZLp2it9RRGxzG+ePcVbj+FWoTTFDdQ7f7245P4VgeLb2+0fxBDd2bFN4Ab0I6fzqbSPiXrRuls9jPIZHTb5hHRiB+gqeQqth6lJRkup09x4atfDGnE6lrKukY4iXBOfxNea+JtUk1GVo4S4t1P7tM/qam8U+IG1LUmY/KoP3c5we9ZCzLz+ta06aWp9dk2VqjBVKm7Mp7cS3ClgQc4apZdFfaXhYcc4bin3zCDF2sTSKhy6DqR7e9bNhdQXtuk1uweNxww5GK2Vke/KTiro5aW0njOWQggdRzV/w/r1/o8+63mYp/EhOVP4dq0LqaCKR0Kl3qs9rb3CsxjK479KUoJkyjCtDlmro9K8KeKdM1jZBJILa6OB5bnhj7Gp/iJbhNIRyuSCAK8dWN41Z1JTaflyRXWaZ4wnutLOmam0dxJGA8bk/MQOqn14rmnCx81jMkjSqe1o7D/CmtnQ9TltpcG1mYKuegavS7TUhJD8sYOfQ14xqyRlvtIVUMg+XJ4J7VRkvNSiXC3UsAAxhXIH6Vi1cdTKVjLTi7M96k1BUjLuFVQMkk4ArlNb+I2l2i7LFReT7sYU4UfjXkF22oXCY84ye2/rUdnY35P+qz81HIzfDcPUafvVJXPRV8c67fbtpit4yMHYmD+dY2o3U83E1xLIS3diagtLOWCH/SCVyM4HertqljcPhjh+eGrVRR1LD0ab9yJlNEVDFNxJ9BSGO5mAURHOe4rolktFwkCGQ9D5alv1qUwXTHK2yw8/edufyFNJXNOdIwYNImaMMWWMY556VM2nRQ2rTu+5V74610aWS43yuX44GMLWdqUK6rdGwilWNI8FgvX6VTSM3PW5Bp1rFNarJGowRWtb2kKMoKqMnrRBDa6ZbLDu3tjhe5rofC2kPdXIvL1MDqinoBUSkkzzsdjfZQbuLHZQ+SEMYwRzkYzVS7sgso2R/LXTatHDFMqR8HbyKhtrbzlZ8cKKhRTep8XOcpyu2fGSr855xxV3RrZrm/ihQ/ebn6VBMmJhgYyK3fBaKNWLHAIRsCvLsrH6ZiJOnRlI73WVKpDgkjywPrVOwt0uZzFLIsYx1Iq9q3NtA+eiCsS7JCMQ2Oe3FfOwm6OJ5o9GeVJfWKFn1NV9Dtm/5eLY/7yA1m6vpyWUSmOWNsk8RgLWZ5s/H71sYzyQaYXlbJZpOOgOMGvosRmVSvT5GjyMNlioT50wGCvDAgDnnNQ3Hyyjg46Ahf61YV9wBIx8vQsBmq1wBuLcMCeeS2K4dEehEiQ5zn8uuPwqewAN9ErnjcM89B/So1YbdpPy46dP0FSWkbmdCQVTcOSKqnNKaKkrxZd8TwtDq80argKfkOeNvbHtiuYteddjwOd5/ka6EeOvDLxGw1pmLQZWKeBAWUA4CnPUVxupeKtKTUGmsUldlJ8sMAo6HrX10ZKx8HNa6HtHwdUHw5ZnbyVr1K2Rdq/KK80+Cab/DFmxA4TPFeoxABFIGKjcpChe3tnpS7Bn0pykgbtwHFKACSWOaUkUIVGBj9K5PxPGP7WWTO1VYc47Hj/CusZsEAelc/4kjV/MbdyIyw7dMUloyWjzC/R47h7yUSL5I2xk93PA/LmvUPBrzNodqLgksIwMn0xxXCeIC2pahbxLGESaXcFUcYHGf0NelabGkVokQB2quBirlJMnl11OdvLJLvxPbxXCkxI3m7c8NgdD+OK7aLU0gkIVgDnkdAfpXN37eTqMd4kbSeXkuAM5XHNN1tZonW5GXjkGVYdGrnnqzppRTPPfitpQtdda9jKlLr5/lGAD3FcaoBIOP84r1vxcr6toBiuYR5yJuhkxyT6GvIC+ydo3BUgkEVDP0fJsZ7Sioy3RNgquc4PWu98AfEK70cJZakDc2g4BJyyfT2rhowZDwKnS2bOSRV9D0sVhKWJg4zR6h448WWt/ZKdNsXu0UgmZhgD2HcmsW5ttPu7hZrLfHJEAy4ON7DJJ/GuW0u5ksZwrFmibqK39BkL+K7WH70fPHrnNU9jya+VUqVCy1sWJ7WJ3klglRjuJKg5x7VEkQxg53fSuH8R2Gq6drN3JD9oRWlYjaTg81Rh8Qa1bsFa4l4Pekqtuh7mHoN042fQ9HEEjAqgyD1FYzPdeF9R3vGW024bLAc+UfX6Vj2PjPVGIUIJmxyNvJ/Kth9ZvL+3MU+gyPG3XAOD+FU5qWtjR0JrsaExElwJ42DhsFfRqdcXJEO1iy5OSQKydDkvdNnMUlpKbMcqHwWj9vpXSQz2syBgwcdgv8AWtYyTRhKLgzJintApDySuD1UrwaranLBJayR6dbpHNJxvI5Fby28EpYrCNvqBzVO70yIXPlz7FSTlCvVT6UpRuOLUlqP0ULLYrYXxAYrlGY8E1S1hJrFzCjArjvzUkujGNfMjvZxjoGbI/WrcAivoTZ3+FnI/dyDvXNKLTPDxcamEn7WGsTmX1HacyRR5IxkDrUNvqKRzblnaME/3qb4l0a7tXwvzR+pFYcOn3s0jRQxISD1VaXMzCWdRtoj0C01FLmNTLcbyBipxGhO5Zgc9q5fRdA1sqQWUAjocVu2uh60i481aTmjglm6b0Rt2d5PboEEgZB2I6Van1qVF2qqtz0GQawW0vXkU7XNN8nxMjfLNKPoopqZlLNn0RuRahqs52wadM3vt4q3pXh3VnuJLoqLd3OSSwzXOxf8JcWA+23OO9aUNv4gm+WS9usH1JFRKTuYTzWo1ZKx2OmaFaWEvn395Gz9SWfpVy88YWFmTa2C/aZRxuA+WuIOh3TYMszFvck1ZttHjt2DzSAc52g8mp3Z5devOprJ3Ow0meXUZTM7EA8szelXNS1SJIDZWJ3HoziueS5lFt5aN5UWMBV6tUBuGjHk24Akc1umjhe9z5mkYmdeav6ZeGwv4505wcEe1ZKuTPz2qeR8vketeQ9j9VfLUhyvY9XkuEu9EtbhBhWQdqybsFoWUAnPoKtaH8/hK0J9CP1NQSOseSxwB3r5ms7Vm0eZypJpGO8cgOFjb67KUxnbnyiRjslaIu4CeJE/Oqs62ZYt5+3JyQHrtp1m90YSSQwI3lZKsSB0xUAMZkYTy4GeBu/SrYSyCBmfII/vZzVS4+zrMFiJC+gWtlPm0M+UGnt4h8kftnGB+ZqFZXmdMD5N3bp+dJcBF5KA+m45pkcmyWNmyee/+FbQjyyQqmkWeW6tbXL6tdpDBI485uik/wARqzp3hjXb2ZFh0y4OT3jwK+wdJ8KaZLZQ3BtYMvGrE7Bzkda14NEsoG3LFGMeiivqKeqR8PL4mcd8K9JvNN8O2ltcJsdEGRXeI3AySTTlhSOMKFH4U6KM9hWmiEOAO35epFPCuBljSoOfvYOKczfKe9RzXJ5iNfUrnFSxeE5vEVncmG5W2BXy94GSCcZqAs2c5x9K8v8Aibq2tx6gttp95dR2wXcyxORk5x2+lJlR1O21fwG+iNpTT6lFOIyYQcYZicnpW2RZ2kX76dEAH8bAV45peh67DAuo3N1NJMfmCSTNlf160w+NbuxWSTU9BjtwjhVklJkVwTjcCfp0qJXtc6aUKL+Nntvh+5sLuWc2jLNtXYSRxyDXD3HiddJ124sbyK3/ALOH3vMk2/MBzt9Oa6CPXraw8VWvh5Ej/wBJ09rhZVULkj2HtXinjHWE1LRJPEr2cUn2e7aOQMOBh8H9MVhzM09yMny7HsctpZ6toEmo+H7uG4DoSIiQzJ7Y618++MYL3TNSlN3A68klgDj616LoGsWs+m2+oaWBAGUOoTjH4Vp3XiLS9Rha316wSc/89VUA/iKXNY9DBY+WHeh47pmsDbsDZXHWtqLUY/LJIz9K29W+HGh6xK934a1eK1dhnyJThc+lczfeBfGWlTbX0ye4TtJb/vFP5VanY+swedU5pKTLKX8MjAL/AD6V1vhmRV1ywcYWRp8A+2K84livbSYJf28sLg5/eIVIrstCkP8AwkmlohJZMlx6YH/16pVLnoYutGdFtPodDe6lajUp7aSaMlZCpViB396cdN025OHsoGU8lto6V5z4nmmfXb9DC5HnuQVHPU1FYX99ZSB0nmiGf4s4rSNa+ljqoUb0otPoj1a20mwthut7aKIHnhccVleIvEul6UpQyA3GfuJ1FQQ67YalpyJdao1o+NsioQN344rFudB8LOryx30k8jHp5mTVTlZWiVGMr63ILLVrjxDeFRmOPuF4wPrW5baVdadKZbdy8UnUE5IrP05tO0O0KWYxK/JLVBd67czrta549uKUGluzSzlojY1nVmt7QW1rgSP94qelY0OrTRKSz7z7+vrVBp1c5Zy1Ruw6AA/hTcm9jRUklY2LrX724RfmVMDBOOT71lyXdxJIJDO7Mpypz0NRowUEEZzTWYAnGKlsToxlFxa0OlttXGoQCC7YCQrtIJ+9TrFILK+2twrHAPp+NclJcIhBLbcdKntNdhmdYLiZeD8jY/TNZOx8dmuTOj+8o7dj1uxSE2vyOASOo61JY28ZnJdyAPWuK0XUJYSqM7PE3cN0rrrK7u4XBiJKOBwcVKj2PlW1B2mbeIXBTeDmm+Wu7aB37VLFeIQBMYTkc7hir8NrBcAuv2dcd1cZqeRhzxfUrQxqFGccetL9rIl2bFCA/erYsNKjkBZ8yIPQipLnTrAyjy4SrjqOuaLE1HFbGJdXCqCsC7j/ABOFrPXSWluRcTgxqwz7muh1SW1trR1kYRke3FeS/Eb4oR2EjaRoAW4vSNpl/hT/ABotfQ55SVjvdRurW0IhiGHPfvVa1kiXLFgzE814v4a069ub7+1NY1Seadm3lVkI5969LtLxdq4JNdEKfLuYuVz/2Q==
```

Can someone tell me why this is not working?

Comment: Also show the code hat put the bitmap as base64 encoded.

Comment: You should change string to byte and not passing the data image and pass only the image bytes

Comment: Where do you get encodedImage from?

Comment: @greenapps it's the base64 String

Comment: @greenapps I receive the String in json format from a network call

Comment: @MCZ How do you mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211156/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array-in-java#3211685

Comment: Can you give us your correct base64 string ? There are some dots in the middle of that one ([..] MyQpsdQp…vE6kMvBBGKt6PrGoaTL52n3MkLg [...] )

Comment: If it is not Androud that encodes a Bitmap then the bitmaps will not be interchangeble. You better not use a bitmap at all if all that you want to do is transfer a file. So i asked for the code that encoded the string. You did not even react.

Comment: @greenapps I did answer to your answer tho. I do not own the code which encodes the bitmap, I just receive this String in Json format from a network call.

Answer (score 2):

you have to remove the leading `data:image/jpeg;base64,` from your base64 string.

```
public void displayUserImage() {
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage.split(",")[1], Base64.DEFAULT);

    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
    imageViewUser.setImageBitmap(b);
}
```

should work.

But of course you should always check if your base64 string contains this information and then delete it otherwise it's fine.