# How can I convert an ImageIcon to a String for storage in a JSON

Tags: java, json, imageicon

Hello and thank you for your help in advance.

I'm working on an rpg character builder. Each character is stored as a JSON file and I would like to include the character image. This was stored as an ImageIcon, but it can't be stored in a JSON.

How can I convert the ImageIcon to a String and back again?

This is what I have so far:

```
public ImageIcon getImageIcon() {
    byte b[];
    ByteArrayInputStream bi;
    ObjectInputStream si;
    ImageIcon image = null;

    try {
        b = this.imageIcon.getBytes(); 
        bi = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
        si = new ObjectInputStream(bi);
        image = (ImageIcon) si.readObject();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    return image;
}

public void setImageIcon(ImageIcon imageIconIn) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bo;
    ObjectOutputStream so;
    try{
        bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        so = new ObjectOutputStream(bo);
        so.writeObject(imageIconIn);
        so.flush();
        this.imageIcon = bo.toString();
    } catch (IOException ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

The problem is I get the following error when converting the String back to an ImageIcon:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: EFBFBDEF
```

I think the setImageIcon() method is fine, but I'm not sure how to fix the  getImageIcon() method.

I'm using Java 1.8 and GSON 2.8.0

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: my idea is you can convert image to base64 string then store it.

Answer (score 0):

Your icon should be either stored:

- inline in your JSON file as a String using [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) encoding.

  - see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211156/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array-in-java)
- in a separate file, and the filename stored as a String in the JSON.

  - `{ "iconFile": "./characters/dwarf.png" }`